# Selecting nearest lines to point layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, spatial-join

I am a beginner with GIS software and I'm working on QGIS.

I have a problem joining the spatial layers. I have a layer with objects in one city and another layer with the streets. I need to attach each object to its street.

I try to join attributes by location but I have not been able because it does not take into account the objects that are on the edge of the street (the roundabouts and bridges).

So how can I make a join between a point and a layer of layer lines using the closest distance by QGIS.

Comment: I would add SEXTANTE and GRASS plugins to your QGIS also  PostGIS is valuable tool when manipulating spatialdata

Comment: v.distance in GRASS can be used for this, but since v.distance does not work in QGIS processing, I have made a QGIS plugin called NNJoin that does nearest neighbour spatial joins.  The result of the join is a new layer that includes the attributes from both of the input layers and adds a new attribute with the nearest neighbour distance.  The plugin is available in the QGIS plugin repository.  It does not use spatial indexes for non-point join layers, so it is not practical for large datasets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find the mmqgis plugin does what you want, it will need to be installed, Fetch Plugins

http://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis/

Comment: Please be more specific about which of the MMQGIS tools you suggest for the job.

Comment: I think the MMQGIS Distance to Hub tool is what is being referred to, however it will treat lines and polygons as points positioned at their centres when calculating the nearest hub, and this can generate misleading results.

Comment: Agreed Andy H, but limited information from the OP.

Answer (score 1):

v.distance in GRASS can be used for this, but since v.distance currently does not work in QGIS processing, I have made a QGIS plugin called NNJoin that does nearest neighbour spatial joins. The result of the join is a new layer that includes the attributes from both of the input layers and adds a new attribute with the nearest neighbour distance. The plugin is available in the QGIS plugin repository.  More information on  http://arken.umb.no/~havatv/gis/qgisplugins/NNJoin/

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of the NNJoin plugin. It was recently updated and you can download the plugin via the Plugin Tools. 
It's very straightforward, and fast:

[image]